# Javascript files conflict when autocomplete search on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have two javascript file on my project.if I close one of these files, the other works. But they dont work together.How can I use ?

This file helps work dropdown

```
<script src="~/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This file helps work Autocomplete search textbox

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Autocomplete search Code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {        
        $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
            source: '/Home/Search/',
            messages: {
                noResults: 'no results',
                results: function (amount) {
                    return amount + 'results.'
                }
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use 2 `jquery` files at the same time?

Comment: I think you should remove `"~/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"`  redundant file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use these two js instead of three js,it will resolve your issue

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ishwar-gagare you are right but there is another javascript method in the project.

That file didn't work when I did it like you said. I add  $.noConflict(); , problem solve . Thank you :)